# CABasicAnimation after UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: objective-c, ios6, cabasicanimation, uipangesturerecognizer

I want to animate a `CALayer` back to its initial position after using a    `UIPanGestureRecognizer` that dragged it somewhere else on the screen.

Here is what I've got:

```
@interface ViewController () {
    CGPoint defaultButtonPosition;
    CGPoint lastPosition;
}
@end


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    defaultButtonPosition = _roundShape.layer.position;

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    [_roundShape displayShape];

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:_roundShape.layer];

}

//code so I can drag my CALayer
- (IBAction)dragShape:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.view];
    sender.view.center = CGPointMake(sender.view.center.x + translation.x, sender.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [sender setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

    lastPosition = sender.view.center;

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSLog(@"Pan ended");
        [self animateBackToOriginalPosition];

       _roundShape.center = lastPosition;
    }
}


- (void)animateBackToOriginalPosition
{        
    CABasicAnimation *moveBackToOriginalPosition = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    moveBackToOriginalPosition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];

    moveBackToOriginalPosition.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:lastPosition];
    moveBackToOriginalPosition.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:defaultPosition];
    moveBackToOriginalPosition.repeatCount = 0;
    moveBackToOriginalPosition.duration = 1.0;
    [_roundShape.layer addAnimation:moveBackToOriginalPosition forKey:@"position"];

}
```

The animation that occurs from this code is nowhere near what I want. When I let go of the CALayer that I am dragging, it suddenly disappears and animates from seemingly random places to the lastPosition instead of the toValue (=defaultPosition) that I set. After that the CALayer isn't visible anymore.

It seems that when I drag the CALayer the position property doesn't change as NSLog always tells me it's still at defaultPosition. That's why I tried using `_roundShape.center = lastPosition;` but this just causes the CALayer to vanish. Without this the CALayer stays visible on screen.

I hope I explained my problem well enough. I'd love to hear what newbie mistakes I made in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to know what are the coordinates of your CGPoint defaultButtonPosition (and type it correctly into your CAAnimation code) with nslog or a printf.
The "vanishing view" comes most of the time from coordinates that are situated far away from the visible window: here, the default point was set before adding the layer to the view, but the last position is set afterwards. Try to change this, or call

```
 convertPoint: toView:
```

Comment: So I've tried setting the defaultPosition after adding the layer to the view but it didn't make any difference. I created the layer's view  with IB so maybe that's why there isn't any difference. NSLog shows me the correct position.

The problem seems to be that I cannot get lastPosition. When I drag the layer away from its defaultPosition NSLog tells me that lastPosition is the same as defaultPosition. So it seems like what I am dragging is not the layer but a copy (?) of the layer.

Comment: Aren't you NSLogging the center of the view containing the layer? Also, the layer should be animated using layer.position (you may use CATransform3DMakeTranslation once you can get the correct coordinates), and take care to set your anchor point correctly in your pangesturerecognizer method. Moving layers raises a lot of coordinates problems, you need to fully understand how a selected point in your layer will be considered in the view and in the main window.

Comment: Okay I now get the right lastPosition. Another mistake I made was that I connected the UIPanGestureRecognizer to the wrong view! I noticed after I saw that a UILabel was moving as well although it was not supposed to do so.

Now the layer does move to the correct position but disappears after moving there and goes back to where I dragged it. Should be easy to fix now.

Comment: Fine! Do not hesitate to update your code so that we can help a little more if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using transformation matrices, it's much easier and suitable for temp transformations. when you want a layer to translate to its original position you just equal the trans matrix to the identity matrix (this way you don't need to keep your prev position either)

Comment: I may try this but I thought it'd be easy to just animate the change in position of a layer.